# Specify a React Component as defaultProp of another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, `Section` and `Button`. I want `Section` to accept `Button` or a `String` as it's children prop. How do I specify `Button` as Section's default children prop.

```
const Button = () =>
    <button type="button">Test</button>

const Section = props => {
  const { children } = props
    return (
      <div>{children}</div>
    )
}

Section.defaultProps = {
    children: /* ??? */
}

Section.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
Section.defaultProps = {
    children: 'Section Test'     //Works fine
}
```

But:

```
Section.defaultProps = {
    children: Button /* does not work */
}
```

I get the following error:

`Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message implied, instead of using `Button` use `<Button />`.

```
Section.defaultProps = {
  children: <Button />
}
```

See [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/1qrmp45nkj)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practice to specify other components as a default prop because you are breaking loose coupling and your Button should have it's own props like `text` and `onClick` to be functional. But if you want it like that you can do the conditional rendering.

```
const Section = props => {
  const { children } = props
  const content = children ? children : <Button />
  return (
    <div>{content}</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please can you throw more light on the loose coupling part. I am a bit confused because your sample code is practically doing the same thing as using `defaultProp`...

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya Loose coupling is a pattern where you don't import and use Presentational Component inside another Presentational Component. It's bad for testing, because if you test `Section` it will automatically include `Button` and if this `Button` component will throw an error your `Section` component will result in error too. It also breaks `tree-shaking` since your `Button` will always be included in your bundle, even if it's never used anywhere else.

For more take a look at this [Medium article](https://reallifeprogramming.com/how-to-structure-components-in-react-54fc43e71546).